# How to grab the id of the channel the bot just made

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do I get the id of the channel that my bot just created?

```
async execute(interaction, client) {
    interaction.guild.channels
      .create({
        name: "channel",
        type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        permissionOverwrites: [
          {
            id: interaction.guild.id,
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages],
          }
        ],
      })
      interaction.reply({content: 'eh'})
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create` returns a promise, and once resolved, the created `Channel`, so the following would work for you:

```js
async execute(interaction, client) {
  let channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
    name: 'channel',
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: interaction.guild.id,
        deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages],
      },
    ],
  });
  // here is the new channel ID
  console.log(channel.id);

  interaction.reply({ content: 'eh' });
}
```